Setting up KOMA-Script for use in Emacs org-mode
I have Linux Mint and want to use KOMA-Script in Emacs org-mode. When running a
simple sample template from here it generates a number of errors,
particularly "Unknown LaTeX Class 'default-koma-letter'". I have
already posted this to the Emacs community (see here), but was
referred to this exchange, as it likely has to do with my TeX Live set
up. I have the following version of TeX Live installed:
"pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev"

Following the advice from here,
I ran the command sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended,
which produced the following output:
texlive-latex-recommended is already the newest version (2021.20220204-1).
texlive-latex-recommended set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1 linux-headers-5.15.0-91
  linux-headers-5.15.0-91-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-92
  linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-97
  linux-headers-5.15.0-97-generic linux-image-5.15.0-91-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic linux-image-5.15.0-97-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-91-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-97-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-91-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-97-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.

Judging by this, I already seem to have TeX Live installed, but
KOMA-Script isn't used when exporting from org-mode. Which steps do I
need to take to further investigate this resp. to resolve this? As a
secondary issue, should I run sudo apt autoremove, as suggested by the
terminal, or is this likely to corrupt my TeX Live installation? Any help and prompters would be much appreciated - I am still new to this world!

You can safely use sudo apt autoremove and then delete it from your question, as it is not really relevant to your problem. I would search for that KOMA-Script in google/whatever and see what provides it in Mint, from my quick search it looks like latex-texlive-extra or -recommended.

You need to simplify your setup: mixing in Org-mode and the Koma classes and LaTeX and installation problems leads to a very confusing soup. First, make sure that you have installed LaTeX correctly by taking an example LaTeX file (either written by you or from a LaTeX tutorial somewhere - make sure that it does not use any extra packages) and compile it from the command line to get a PDF. Until that works, don't go any further! Fix all the problems and only when you have succeeded, then try to install the Koma package(s) and then do the same thing: use the simplest file that uses ...

... a Koma class, and process it from the command line until you get the output you expect. Only then, go back to Emacs and Org-mode. Divide-and-conquer works!
